# c# - How can I write a file to memorystream, zip three of those memorystreams, and put that into another memorystream?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

First, I want to create three files without actually creating a file like memorystream. I want to compress those three files and put them in a memoeystream.
It is possible to put a zip file in memoeystream, but like memorystream, can it actually contain three files without creating a file?

Here is my code,

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (ZipArchive fileContainer = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) {
        using(MemoryStream fileMS = new MemoryStream()){ 
        //I want to create file to like memorystream, Not local  
        //file txt1.txt  contain 123456789        
        //file txt2.txt  contain 12345
        //file txt1.txt  contain 6789    
        }            
    }
    return File(ms.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Result.zip");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked fine for me

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry($"text{i}.txt");
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("text");
                        }
                    }

                }
               return File(ms.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Result.zip");
            }
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it